# Using Ajax with cakephp doesnt work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I have a page like this:
[image]

Basically, I pick 2 dates and hit the button, then the data below will change without refreshing this page.

Here is the code in controller:

```
if( $this->request->is('ajax') ) {

        $this->autoRender = false;

        //if ($this->request->isPost()) {
            print_r($this->request->data);
            // get values here 
            echo $from=( $this->request->data('start_time'));
            echo $to= $this->request->data('end_time');
            Debugger::dump($from);
            Debugger::dump($to);


        //$this->layout = 'customer-backend';
        $this->Order->recursive=-1;
        $this->Order->virtualFields['benefit']='SUM(Product.product_price - Discount.product_discount)';
        $this->Order->virtualFields['number']='COUNT(Order.order_id)';
        $option['joins'] = array(
            array('table'=>'discounts',
                'alias'=>'Discount',
                'type'=>'INNER',
                'conditions'=>array(
                    'Order.discount_id = Discount.discount_id',
                )
            ),
            array('table'=>'products',
                'alias'=>'Product',
                'type'=>'INNER',
                'conditions'=>array(
                    'Discount.product_id = Product.product_id'
                )
            )
        );
        $option['fields']= array('Discount.product_id','Product.product_name','benefit','number');
        $option['conditions']=array('Discount.start_time >='=>$from);
        $option['group'] = array('Discount.product_id','Product.product_name');
        //$option['limit']=20;
        $products = $this->Order->find('all',$option);
        //Debugger::dump($products);
        $this->set('products',$products);
    //}
    }
    else
    {
        $from='27 November 2012';
        //$this->layout = 'customer-backend';
        $this->Order->recursive=-1;
        $this->Order->virtualFields['benefit']='SUM(Product.product_price - Discount.product_discount)';
        $this->Order->virtualFields['number']='COUNT(Order.order_id)';
        $option['joins'] = array(
            array('table'=>'discounts',
                'alias'=>'Discount',
                'type'=>'INNER',
                'conditions'=>array(
                    'Order.discount_id = Discount.discount_id',
                )
            ),
            array('table'=>'products',
                'alias'=>'Product',
                'type'=>'INNER',
                'conditions'=>array(
                    'Discount.product_id = Product.product_id'
                )
            )
        );
        $option['fields']= array('Discount.product_id','Product.product_name','benefit','number');
        $option['conditions']=array('Discount.start_time >='=>$from);
        $option['group'] = array('Discount.product_id','Product.product_name');
        //$option['limit']=20;
        $products = $this->Order->find('all',$option);
        $this->set('products',$products);
    }
```

If the request is ajax, it gets 2 values `$from` and `$to` from the POST and pass them to the SQL query. If the request is not ajax (mean the access this page for the first time when the dates havent picked yet), $from and $to are assigned default values.

Here is my ajax in view:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
    var from = $('#from').val();
    var to = $('#to').val();
    alert(from+" "+to);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/project/cakephp/orders/hottest_products",
        type: 'POST',

        data: {"start_time": from, "end_time": to },
        success: function(data){
            alert("success");
        }
    });
});
});
```

it gets data from 2 date picker then send it to the controller as a POST method.

My problem is that after I choose 2 dates and hit the button, nothing happens. the data doesnt change according to the dates.
Any thoughts about this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your URL seems way off - have you verified it's actually hitting the right action?  If so, what does it display?  Have you tried looking at the "Network" tab in Chrome's Developer Tools (or similar)?

Comment: @Dave when I hit the button, it sent a POST request to the server, containing 2 values. I used firebug in Firefox. 
<code>POST hottest_products 200 OK </code>

Comment: And what is returned?  An error message?  ...etc?

Comment: it returned nothing. except the POST request. Nothing changed. You can check it here http://cmpt470.csil.sfu.ca:8019/project/cakephp/orders/hottest_products  Account is: admin@hotmail.com and pass is 123456. After login, please access the link above again.

Comment: @Dave I'm not sure this code is right or not
$option['conditions']=array('Discount.start_time >='=>$from);

 But by passing the $from = '27 November 2012', it should show some data. It worked on mysql, but doesnt work here.

Comment: If you're going to be using ajax, you need to learn how to debug it.  Until you can actually show what the ajax is returning, then it's strictly a JavaScript/ajax question, which you should post as such.

Comment: Example: make an empty page, and try to hit it w/ Ajax.  Ignore ALL the controller/action/cakephp stuff, and JUST get ajax to work.  Then work your way up from there.

Comment: I also got the data in fireBug. Here is what it returned in the POST method.

Array
(
    [start_time] => 03 December 2013
    [end_time] => 21 December 2013
)

Comment: Now you're  making progress!  Now you just have to rewrite your question so it explains what it is you're actually asking, then you're good to go.

Comment: I didnt make any progress, that's what I got before posting this question. Im done with sending a Post request along with values. However, it somehow didnt work in the controller. I really need your help. I've been stuck at this for 2 days.  :(

Comment: After loging in on the test site it takes me back to login. When trying to send a post request to `/project/cakephp/orders/hottest_products` I get 403 forbidden response.

Comment: @HMR can you try it again. mine is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

When opening your page and running the following in the console:

```
$(".tab_container").html("loaded from ajax");
```

The products table now only shows "loaded from ajax". If the content of the products table is generated by it's own template you can have cakephp render that template only when it's an ajax call:    http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html

```
$this->render('/Path/To/ProductTable/');
```

If your cakephp will output only the product table when an ajax call is made you could try to run the following code:

```
var from = "2000-01-01";
var to = "2014-01-01";
$.ajax({
    url: "/project/cakephp/orders/hottest_products",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {"start_time": from, "end_time": to }
}).then(
  function(result){
    $(".tab_container").html(result);
  },function(){
    console.log("fail",arguments);
  }
);
```

Comment: so you mean I need to format the data in JSON or text/html? Normally, the hottest_product page send a POST request to the controller. The controller use that data to execute a select query to retrieve data from database and then send it back to the page to show the data.

Comment: @TungPham You can use JSON, XML, DOM or just text to return as long as the JavaScript does something with it. If you return a DOM part you can just replace the innerHTML of something with the newly returned part. If the table of products is in it's own template then you can render that and have JS set the innerHTML of the container of that table with the returned html. I assumed you wanted to use JSON but html would be easier to implement.

Comment: I just want to use something simple, as long as I can make it work.

Comment: At the page: http://cmpt470.csil.sfu.ca:8019/project/cakephp/orders/hottest_products is the code contained in the div with class tab_container generated by it's own template? If so you can have cakephp return only the table and then set the innerHTML with the returned content: `$(".tab_container").html(response);`

Comment: The whole code is in <div class="control-group">, but I think it's not a problem as the POST method returned something like: 

Array
(
    [start_time] => 02 December 2013
    [end_time] => 08 December 2013
)
<pre>'2013-12-02'</pre><pre>'2013-12-08'</pre>

 And from Cakephp you can access to POST method by using $this->request->data('name_of_variable');

Comment: Sorry, I dont get it. I mean, Ajax sent the data successfully to the Controller. Now what I have to do is just get these data, input it into a query and show the result of the query on the screen. But I can nt make it work :(

Comment: I found out that I got the data from the Ajax POST request and after inputing it to the select query, I got the data. But the thing is that it didnt send the data to the view, or maybe this code didnt work: $this->set('products',$products);